# Flurry Ads Not Showing Up

Tags: ios, swift, flurry

I am integrating Flurry into my swift app. I have set up all the code correctly (i think) but nothing happens at runtime. I get this message in the console:

```
2015-08-14 23:41:14.509 Ball[734:137593] Flurry: Starting session on Agent Version [Flurry_iOS_155_6.7.0]
```

My AppDelegate.swift file looks like this:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    Flurry.startSession("FLURRY_ID")
    Flurry.logEvent("Launched Application")

    return true
     }
}
```

I don't know if this message is good or bad.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is fine and the Console Log is also good.

The Log displayed only tells that flurry is starting the session. This is displayed when `Flurry.startSession("327C6D7P6CQPKVM4C77V")` is executed.

You should also see other logs regarding Event being logged (displayed when `Flurry.logEvent("Launched Application")` is executed). If not then there should be an **"Error Log"** telling that either the session initialisation failed or the Event Log was un-successful. (If you see an error please also post it).

NOTE: Your code might be working perfectly. If you are looking at the flurry web portal for the results, then know that it takes some time for the logs to show up on your web dashboard. Mostly 3-4 hours (only on iOS), sometimes 24 hours (always for android, sometimes for iOS).